# How to run a background task in PHP web application?

Tags: php, scheduled-tasks, scheduler, background-task

I want to run a background scheduler in my web application. This scheduler will check the current time and if it matches with the programmed time then it sends a E-mail.
How can i create background Scheduler ?

Comment: It's called a cron job. You almost can find it at your server control panel.

Comment: you're looking at it wrong. pretty much every modern OS already HAS a "background scheduler". You just need to hook into your specific operating system's version of it and tell it to schedule your php script.

Comment: i want to add scheduler within my application.

Comment: i don't have any knowledge of cron job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends if you want to run a script in background via command line, than you can use `exec` command: [exec](http://php.net/manual/de/function.exec.php)

Or if you want to start another thread, than you can use [pthreads](http://php.net/manual/de/book.pthreads.php)

If you want to have a job that executes at a certain time or in certain intervals, you can set up a cronjob. [This tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/managing-cron-jobs-with-php--net-19428) is very helpful, and if you are on linux you can look at this [documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto).

Comment: yes i want to run a script in a background which will check the current time and if it matches with the time of script then it should send a mail to particular email id.

Comment: edited my answer ^^ cronjob will be the thing you are looking for

Comment: thank you for your help i will check it out.

Answer (score 2):

You need to setup cron job. You may find more information [a link](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/Cron+Jobs)!